# Sortable menu items (into submenus) with jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, menu, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a horizontal jQuery menu item with the `sortable` option. It has one submenu. 
I want to:

1. Keep the menu item with the submenu locked at the end of the list
2. Be able to drag menu items from the main menu to the submenu and change styles automatically
3. Be able to save the layout for when the page is opened again

Currently I can move all the menu items, but I can't move them from one level to another. I tried using the `connect` option, but it didn't work.

Sorry if I am missing something obvious; I'm very new to jQuery UI (not jQuery).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3sUvm/12/

EDIT: Updated incorrect demo link

Comment: I think you are looking for this, http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists you need to use a connect list, just provide the `css selector` and then you are done...

Comment: I tried that, but it isn't working with the menu's submenu.

Comment: Ok, I don't know how useful this will be but, http://markmintoff.com/2011/05/jqueryui-hierarchical-sorting/ or google `jquery hierarchical sortable` or something like that you should get loads of tuts.

Comment: That looks like the right plugin, but it doesn't work at all. I tried to call it in my jsFiddle and it broke the sortability completely: http://jsfiddle.net/3sUvm/14/

Comment: Ah, I had the wrong list type. It still doesn't work nicely with `menu` though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Your problem is because the containement, however I think you are looking for something like this....

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists-through-tabs

`$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable().disableSelection();`

Add a class on the last `li` where `more` is:

```
$('.dop-here').droppable({
            accept: ".googlebar li",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                // do something here...
            }
        });
```

I hope this helps,

So you want to make it droppable and the `drop` function will be triggered once an item has been dropped and if it's an item...

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists-through-tabs that is the demo, but instead of tabs, you will have a drop down menu, drag an item to any of the tabs and drop it, the thing you want to focus on, is the `drop:function` click the view source and play around with it, because that way not only will get it right, but you get to understand the code you place :) (teaching you how to fish and not just give you a fish)